# Bound on third moment when the variable is bounded and has finite expectation

Tags: probability-theory

If I have a random variable $X$ such that $|X| \leq 1$ and $\mathbb{E}(X) = c < \infty$, I want to find the tightest upper bound for $\mathbb{E}(X^3)$. What would be the most optimal bound to use?

Comment: Let $P(X=1)=c$ and $P(X=0)=1-c$.  Then $E(X)=E(X^3)=c$.   I suspect this is optimal.  In general you need to know the distribution of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^3$ and let $S\subset \mathbb R^2$ be the convex hull of the points $\{(x,f(x)): x\in[-1,1]\}$. The set $S$ is the set of all possible $(EX,EX^3)$ values for random variables $X$ with $P(|X|\le1)=1.$ The intersection of $S$ with the vertical line cut out by $x=c$ is the interval from $(c,L(c))$ to $(c,U(c))$, where $L$ and $U$ are the lower convex  and upper concave envelopes  of $f$ on $[-1,1]$.  Then the desired upper bound is $U(c)$.

More explicitly: Draw a line through $(1,1)$, tangent at $(-1/2, -1/8)$ to the graph of $f$. The graph of $U$ follows that of $f$ for  $x\in[-1,-1/2]$ and that of the tangent line for $x\in[-1/2,1]$.  The formula for $U$ is $$U(x)=\begin{cases}-x^3&x\le -1/2\\ -\frac 1 8 +\frac 3 4 (x+1/2)& x\gt-\frac 1 2 \end{cases}.$$

If $c=0$, for example, $U(0)=1/4$, which is attained by a random variable $X$ taking the value $X=1$ with probability $1/3$ and the value $X=-1/2$ with probability $2/3$. Then $$EX^3=\frac 2 3 (-\frac 1 8 )+\frac 1 
 3(1)=\frac 1 4 .$$

Comment: Why does this property of belonging to the convex hull holds?

Comment: @Daniel You mean, that $S$ has all possible $(EX,EX^3)$ pairs in it?  Intuitively, because the $E$ operator averages, and the convex hull of a set is the set of all possible averages.  A high-brow version of this idea is the basis of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_theory .

Comment: I never saw this idea, but it seems interesting. I can see easily that $X$ being a constant with probability 1 implies $(c, f(c))$ is in the possible pairs, and thus that any point in the convex hull is possible by considering the random variable $X$ that is assumes value $c_1$ with probability $\alpha$ and $c_2$ with probability $1 - \alpha$. However I do not see how to ensure that a general random variable is also in $S$. *edit* I see it now, just consider a sequence of discrete random variables converging to the general one... Thanks!

Comment: @Daniel  The same reasoning should make you believe this for "simple" random variables, taking on finitely many values only.  There are 2 parts to my claim: each $(EX,EX^3)$ is a point in $S$, and that each point in $S$ arises this way.  Which gives you more trouble?

Comment: A truly clever idea. I have never thought in such way. Thanks!

Comment: @kimchilover The one I did not understand before was about every point in $S$ arising in this way. But now I see that the argument holds for simple random variables and then for general ones by limit arguments. Thanks!

Comment: @HanareSakuraba  I think of it as the "method of moments".  I agree, it is a very slick way of thinking about probability and integrals, about 100 years old, associated with people like Caratheodory and Helly.  Your problem is a good example to showcase this method on.

Comment: @Daniel By Caratheodory's theorem ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_(convex_hull) ) each point in $S$ is a convex combo of finitely many points in the graph of $f$.  So the simple rv supported by those points exhibits a random variable with corresponding moments.